# Как оптимизировать мой код?

Tags: java, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Я новичок в Java (программировал в Pascal) и мне нужно написать программу для решения следующего задания (что-то вроде числового ребуса):

```
AB + CC = DC
CE * FB = CEB
FF * GC = GHC
AB - CE = FF
CC + FB = GC 
DC + CEB = GHC
```

П.С. Каждый символ одна цифра (от 0 до 9). Каждая цифра может использоваться только один раз.

Итак, я написал следующую программу:

```
public class javaapplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean bb=false;
        for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
            for (int g = 0; g < 10; g++) {
                if (bb) {
                    break;
                }
                for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
                    if (bb) {
                        break;
                    }
                    for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
                        if (bb) {
                            break;
                        }
                        for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
                            if (bb) {
                                break;
                            }
                            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                                if (bb) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
                                    if (bb) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                                        if (a*10 + b + c*10 + c == d*10 + c) {
                                            if ((c*10+e)*(f*10+b)==(c*100+e*10+b)) {
                                                if ((f*10+f)*(g*10+c)==g*100+h*10+c) {
                                                    if ((a*10+b)-(c*10+e) == f*10+f) {
                                                        if ((c*10+c)+(f*10+b) == g*10+c) {
                                                            if ((d*10+c)+(c*100+e*10+b) == g*100+h*10+c) {
                                                                if (a!=b && a!=c && a!=d && a!=e && a!=f && a!=g && a!=h) {
                                                                    if (b!=c && b!=d && b!=e && b!=f && b!=g && b!=h) {
                                                                        if (c!=d && c!=e && c!=f && c!=g && c!=h) {
                                                                            if (d!=e && d!=f && d!=g && d!=h) {
                                                                                if (e!=f && e!=g && e!=h) {
                                                                                    if (f!=g && f!=h) {
                                                                                        if (g!=h) {
                                                                                            bb = true;
                                                                                            System.out.println(a);
                                                                                            System.out.println(b);
                                                                                            System.out.println(c);
                                                                                            System.out.println(d);
                                                                                            System.out.println(e);
                                                                                            System.out.println(f);
                                                                                            System.out.println(g);
                                                                                            System.out.println(h);
                                                                                            break;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Она работает и выдаёт правильные результаты, однако я уверен, что она написано неправильно, так как решение само по себе глупое - чистый подбор. Прошу показать мне, как можно оптимизировать данную программу. 
З.Ы. Большое количество if-ов писал в большей степени для большей понятности кода для себя лично.

Comment: Да, прошу прощение, опечатался. Условие обновил. Та строка выглядит следующим образом: FF * GC = GHC. И ещё: я знаю, что математическое (логическое) решение задачи есть - вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в том, как оптимизировать программу.

Comment: ну самая сильная оптимизация - решить задачу и выводить ответ )

Comment: @pavel предположим, что список условий задаётся динамически )

Comment: Решать самому - это, конечно, хорошо. Но суть в проблемы в том, что заставить компьютер делать это максимально быстро и правильно, корректно использую его возможности и возможности языка.

Comment: первое, что  я бы сразу оптимизировал, это проверка одинаковых цифр. Вы ее делаете в самую последнюю очередь, вынося тяжелые рассчеты в начало. А нужно  наоборот.

У Вас всего 8 цифр. это 10!/2! = 1814400. А в Вашем случае кол-во переборов сложно посчитать, и как следствие, это как максимум 10 в 8.

я попробовал, перебирать только первые 4 цифры (a,b,c,d) и проверять самое первое условие. Как результат - осталось только 32 варианта.

Comment: О, спасибо. Хорошая идея. Я пытался вписать проверку одинаковых чисел перед созданием нового цикла, однако успехом это не закончилось.

Comment: Можно попробовать свести задачу к решению системы линейных уравнений

Comment: @Grundy можно. Apache Math содержит неплохие реализации решений СЛАУ )

Comment: Можно, однако тут слишом много неизвестных для решения стандартными методами.

Comment: @OlehZarudskyi, не, тут просто остается несколько свободных переменных, для которых уже работает перебор, но перебор для двух или трех сравнительно меньше чем для 8

Comment: да, я заметил. Проверив первые два условия "по местному", я бы значительно уменьшил общее количество комбинаций.

Comment: Если в задаче всегда есть условие что один из символов = 0, то можно парсить строки по заданному правилу для поиска 0, а исходя из этого двигаться дальше.

Comment: @I.Perevoz, но в задаче такого условия нет :)

Comment: Два решения: `40 + 22 = 62; 29 * 10 = 290; 11 * 32 = 352; 40 - 29 = 11; 22 + 10 = 32; 62 + 290 = 352` и
`50 + 33 = 83; 39 * 10 = 390; 11 * 43 = 473; 50 - 39 = 11; 33 + 10 = 43; 83 + 390 = 473`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Незачем делать сложный `break` через булеву переменную. Достаточно `return`, это прервёт все циклы.
2. Условие "Каждая цифра может использоваться только один раз" нужно проверять не самым последним, а на этапе перебора.
   Так у вас будет всего `10!/2!=10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3` проверки, а не `10^8`.

   1. Определяете множество всех цифр.
   2. Во внешнем цикле перебор по этому множеству.
   3. В следующем цикле перебор по множеству из предыдущего цикла без той цифры, которая выбрана в предыдущем цикле.
   4. В следующем цикле перебор по множеству из предыдущего цикла без той цифры, которая выбрана в предыдущем цикле... и так далее.
3. Условия можно выделить и хранить как список методов (лямбд), а потом делать проверку в цикле.

Comment: _Java же не позволяет положить метод в переменную?_ - а лямбды, не?

Comment: @Grundy точно, забыл что они там есть )

Comment: Спасибо за return, буду знать."Определяете множество всех цифр.
Во внешнем цикле перебор по этому множеству.
В следующем цикле перебор по множеству из предыдущего цикла без той цифры, которая выбрана в предыдущем цикле.
В следующем цикле перебор по множеству из предыдущего цикла без той цифры, которая выбрана в предыдущем цикле... и так далее." так делать и пытался,  однако выдавало бред полный.. может и ошибка где была. Проверю позже.

Comment: я бы ещё в рекурсию лучше обернул, 10 циклов это слишком) И проверял условия на момент формирования (т.е. сразу когда можно вычислить выражение). Возможно добавил бы вычисление правил, типо если есть 2 слагаемых можно сразу вычислить сумму и не перебирать.

Comment: break с меткой ещё можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, вспомнил про него, но решил обойтись return )

Answer (score 4):

Решение "джаст фор фан", но по производительности даже получше, учитывая распараллеливание:

```
IntFunction<Integer> a = x -> x / 10000000 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> b = x -> x / 1000000 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> c = x -> x / 100000 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> d = x -> x / 10000 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> e = x -> x / 1000 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> f = x -> x / 100 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> g = x -> x / 10 % 10;
IntFunction<Integer> h = x -> x % 10;

IntFunction<IntStream> fx =
    i -> IntStream.range(0, 10).filter(x -> {
        if (x == i) return false;
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j /= 10) {
            if (x == j % 10) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }).map(x -> 10 * i + x);

IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel()
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .flatMap(fx)
    .filter(x -> a.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x) + c.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x) == d.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x))
    .filter(x -> (f.apply(x) * 10 + f.apply(x)) * (g.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x)) == g.apply(x) * 100 + h.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x))
    .filter(x -> (a.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x)) - (c.apply(x) * 10 + e.apply(x)) == f.apply(x) * 10 + f.apply(x))
    .filter(x -> (c.apply(x) * 10 + e.apply(x)) * (f.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x)) == (c.apply(x) * 100 + e.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x)))
    .filter(x -> (c.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x)) + (f.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x)) == g.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x))
    .filter(x -> (d.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x)) + (c.apply(x) * 100 + e.apply(x) * 10 + b.apply(x)) == g.apply(x) * 100 + h.apply(x) * 10 + c.apply(x))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: А можете объяснить, что и как тут делается?